# How do you calculate the standard deviation for gap-statistics using inertia in scikit-learn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, k-means

I am trying to calculate the gap-statistics for determining the best `k` for k-means using `scikit-learn` library.
To unambiguously determine the value of the correct `k` I believe I need to subtract the standard deviation from every subsequent gap and check to see `if gap(k) >= gap(k+1) - std(k+1)`. I do not understand how to determine the value of this standard deviation.

Thanks!

Here's my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans, MiniBatchKMeans
from numpy.random import random_sample
from math import sqrt, log

# returns series of random values sampled between min and max values of passed col
def get_rand_data(col):
    rng = col.max() - col.min()
    return pd.Series(random_sample(len(col))*rng + col.min())

def iter_kmeans(df, n_clusters, num_iters=10):
    rng =  range(1, num_iters + 1)
    vals = pd.Series(index=rng)
    for i in rng:
        k = KMeans(n_clusters=n_clusters, n_init=3)
        k.fit(df)
        print "Ref k: %s" % k.get_params()['n_clusters']
        vals[i] = k.inertia_
    return vals

def gap_statistic(df, max_k=15):
    gaps = pd.Series(index = range(1, max_k + 1))
    for k in range(1, max_k + 1):
        km_act = KMeans(n_clusters=k, n_init=3)
        km_act.fit(df)

        # get ref dataset
        ref = df.apply(get_rand_data)
        ref_inertia = iter_kmeans(ref, n_clusters=k).mean()

        gap = log(ref_inertia - km_act.inertia_)
        print "Ref: %s   Act: %s  Gap: %s" % ( ref_inertia, km_act.inertia_, gap)
        gaps[k] = gap

    return(gaps)
```

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the standard deviation `iter_kmeans(ref, n_clusters=k)` and multiply by `sqrt(1 + 1 / num_iters)`. See the original paper for details: https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/Papers/gap.pdf